# how owa works step by step

Tags: statistics, geospatial, arcgis, geography

raster1 {{0,1},{1,1}}
raster2 {{1,1},{0,0}}

hi can you explain me how the Ordered Weighted Average method works given the above two rasters step-by-step? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part about the concept of OWA is the order of the input vector before the operation. Given a vector and a weighting vector:

```
v = (1, 3, 2, 7)
weights = (0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1)
```

Notice that, as all the weight vectors, the sum of the components must sum 1. Now, construct v1 ordering the components of v:

```
v1 = (7, 3, 2, 1)
```

OK. Now, let's look at the theory of the OWA:

```
OWA = sum v1_i * weights_i
```

so in our example we will get something like this:

```
OWA = 7 * 0.5 + 3 * 0.3 + 2 * 0.1 + 1 * 0.1
```